# Deleting OpenAL Effects

Tags: audio, openal

When calling `alDeleteEffects` to destroy an effect, is it necessary to first remove it from any auxiliary slots that it may be active in?

I know first removing a buffer from a source is necessary, which makes sense, but I saw no mention of it in the [Effects Extension Guide](https://kcat.strangesoft.net/misc-downloads/Effects%20Extension%20Guide.pdf) to indicate either way for effects. It seems that effects are more of a state change rather than used actively like a buffer, as any parameter changes require resetting the effect in the slot, so I am leaning towards "no", but wanted to be sure.